# How to use tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss() with softplus?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I want to train a tensoflow neural network using triplet loss and a softplus function as used in article "In Defense of the Triplet Loss for Person Re-Identification" (2017). I found loss function How to use `tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss()` and the function `tf.nn.softplus()`, but I'm not able to use them together. The network I want to train is:

```
model1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=None), # No activation on final dense layer
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x, axis=1)) # L2 normalize embeddings
])´
```

I know how to use only the loss function `tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss()` as follows

```
model1.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
    loss=tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss())
```

But I don't know how to use it with `tf.nn.softplus()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loss function `tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss()` has a parameter `soft`. So to use softplus function, you just need to do

```
model1.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
    loss=tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss(soft=True))
```

Comment: Where is the reference for this parameter? My version doesn't have such a parameter: https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/losses/TripletSemiHardLoss

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add the activation in your model as the last layer?

```
model1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, padding='same', 
                           activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=None), # No activation on final dense layer
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x, axis=1)) # L2 normalize embeddings,
    tf.keras.layers.Activation('softplus')
])
```